# Changing text color when hovering over text with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a bunch of text on a canvas in Tkinter and I want to make it so the text color changes when the mouse is hovering over the text. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do it, and there doesn't seem to be a lot of information about Tkinter anywhere.

```
for city in Cities:
    CityText = Cities[i]
    board.create_text(CityLocs[CityText][0], CityLocs[CityText][1], text=CityText, fill="white")
    CityText = Cities[i]
    i = i + 1
```

That's just my code to place the text on the canvas, although I'm not sure what else to post to get my point across. Is there no 'hover' function or something like that built into Tkinter?

Comment: You probably want to add tags and/or store the ids to the text objects you're creating so you can access them later

Answer (score 5):

You can bind arbitrary events (mouse, keyboard, window manager and possibly others) to any widget in Tkinter.

A nice documentation for that is at [http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211515/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) -

For example, to bind color changes to widgets when mouse hover over them:

```
import Tkinter
from functools import partial

def color_config(widget, color, event):
    widget.configure(foreground=color)

parent = Tkinter.Tk()
text = Tkinter.Label(parent, text="Hello Text")
text.bind("<Enter>", partial(color_config, text, "red"))
text.bind("<Leave>", partial(color_config, text, "blue"))
text.pack()

Tkinter.mainloop()
```

The use of `functools.partial` here allows you to re-use a variable for your text (Label) widget, since you are appending them to a list. If one would settle to simply using lambda you would have a disgusting surprise, as the variable referring to the widget in the body of  the lambda function would always point to the last value it had inside the `for` loop. `functools.partial` "freeze"  the variable content at the time it is called, and yields a new function.

However, since you are placing the items in a Canas, you can either set the "fill" and "fillactive" attributes for each item, as in @mgilson's answer, or you can create a more generic class to handle not only hovering, but other events you choose to implement later.

If your class has a  `__call__` method, you can pass an instance of it to the `bind` method of the canvas, so that the resulting object is called for each event on the canvas. In this case, mouse-motion event suffices:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Follower(object):
    def __init__(self,on_color="#fff", off_color="#000"):
        self.on_color = on_color
        self.off_color = off_color
        self.previous_item = None
    def hover(self, canvas, item, x, y):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(item)
        if x1 <= x <= x2 and y1 <= y <= y2:
            return True
        return False
        
    def __call__(self, event):
        canvas = event.widget
        item = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        hovering = self.hover(canvas, item, event.x, event.y)
        if (not hovering or item != self.previous_item) and self.previous_item is not None:
            canvas.itemconfig(self.previous_item, fill=self.off_color)
        if hovering:
            canvas.itemconfig(item, fill=self.on_color)
        self.previous_item = item

master=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(master)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text((40,20),text="Hello World!",fill="black")
canvas.create_text((60,80),text="FooBar",fill="black")
canvas.bind("<Motion>", Follower())
master.mainloop()
```

(ps. canvas and text placement example borrowed from @mgilson's answer)

Comment: This is a great answer if the `pack` or `grid` geometry managers are sufficient for your text placement...I suppose the `place` geometry manager could be used too...but that gets ugly pretty quickly I think...

Comment: @mgilson: indeed - aprantly the OP really needs Canvas - this new example should cover it in a more generic way. (I thought one culd bind events to canvas item, when I first wrote the answer - youwill actually need some event manager to re-distribute events to items like the class in the second example here)

Comment: I didn't test it, but it looks pretty solid.  My one reservation is that it looks like your class will *always* pick out an item to have colored with on_color (as long as the cursor is on the canvas anyway).  It's possible if the labels are sparse enough that there would be times when it would be desireable to have none of them active (if the cursor isn't close enough for example) -- or if the cursor leaves (although that's probably an easier fix, set previous_item's color to off_color and set it to None in a method which is bound to "<Leave>").

Comment: It may be simpler to bind on `<Enter>`/`<Leave>` events on item (instead of `<Motion>` and reimplement kind of picking)

Comment: @FabienAndre: that was my first thoguht, but I didn't find a way to bind events on canvas items - do you know how to do it?

Comment: @mgilson: it won't pick an "on_color" if `hovering` is false - that is why I wrote the `hover` method (badly named, and due to the short nature of the example more a "function" than a proper method)

Comment: @jsbueno  just answer it on mgilson answer comments

Comment: @jsbueno You're right.  I didn't notice that.  Very nice.  (I already upvoted your answer btw, but I still maintain that mine is much simpler ;)

Comment: @mgilson: indeed - yours is simple - a code like the one in this answer is only usefull if one is doing other things besides changing color (but them it is a _nice_ recipe of a way to go with event handling on Canvas). I also upvoted yours, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (admittedly) pretty lame example that works on OS-X...

```
from Tkinter import *

master=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(master)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_text((20,20),activefill="red",text="Hello World!",fill="black")
master.mainloop()
```

reference:  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm

Comment: Not bad, but will only work for text elements inside a canvas object - arbitary widgets outside a canvas does not have a 'fill' or 'activefill' attribute.

Comment: @jsbueno : Of course, bind is more generally applicable as you've pointed out.  (That was my first thought too...), but he asked about text elements on a canvas and this is much more simple than binding arbitrary events.  Also, can you bind events to item_handles generated by the create_text method?  If not, the task of tracking down which text element is beneath the cursor becomes even more difficult.

Comment: yes you can, `item = canvas.create_text(...) ; canvas.tag_bind(item, "<Enter>", callback)`. Moreover, as suggested by Joel's comment, you may add a tag to all the corresponding items `create_text(..., tag="city_name")` and perform a binding on this tag.

Comment: You're welcome. Definitely poorly named method since it take either items reference or tag name...

Answer (score 1):

This is already built into Tkinter. Use the 'activefill' option when you create your text to specify which color you want it to be.

See the following link for more information. Effbot.org/tkinterbook is my go to tkinter.
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method