# Italicize tkinter label text on focus

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter label

`back_button = Label(self.about_frame, text = "Back", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Silkscreen", 18))`

and I want to have the text's font change from regular to italic when a user hovers over the label with their mouse. How should I go about implementing this? Thanks!

Comment: Note that hover != focus. What have you tried, and with what (if any) success?

Comment: If I'm binding back_button with an event handler that executes on "<Button-1>", wouldn't the user hovering over the label be equivalent to the canvas having focus on the label? I tried messing with back_button.config and creating a font outside of the label instantiation but with no luck.

Comment: `<Button-1>` is left-click, which is neither hover nor focus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import tkinter
from functools import partial

def font_config(widget, fontslant, event):
    widget.configure(font=fontslant)

parent = tkinter.Tk()
text = tkinter.Label(parent, text="Hello Text")
text.bind("<Enter>", partial(font_config, text, "Helvetica 9 italic"))
text.bind("<Leave>", partial(font_config, text, "Helvetica 9"))
text.pack()

tkinter.mainloop()
```

See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239292/changing-text-color-when-hovering-over-text-with-tkinter) and [this](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php) for more information.

Comment: I tried running this and I got the following error:

self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "Bold"